# Fatal Exception when switching activites - Android

Tags: android, exception

I'm new to programming and in the app I'm building every time I switch from the first activity to the second the app crashes.
This is my code:
Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String MOOD_AMOUNT = "MOOD_AMOUNT";

    public String eaten;
    public String inputData;
    public boolean visual = false;
    public boolean auditory = false;
    public boolean selfInjury = false;

    SeekBar rateMoodSeekBar;
    private double moodAmount;

    EditText moodAmountET;

    CheckBox visualCheckBox;
    CheckBox auditoryCheckBox;
    CheckBox selfInjuryCheckBox;

    RadioGroup eatenRadioGroup;
    RadioButton eatenPoorRadioButton;
    RadioButton eatenOKRadioButton;
    RadioButton eatenWellRadioButton;
    RadioButton eatenNoneRadioButton;

    Button submitButton;
    Button viewFilesButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){

            // Just started

            moodAmount = 50; 

        } else {

            // App is being restored


            moodAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(MOOD_AMOUNT); 


        }

        // Initialize the EditTexts

        moodAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rateMoodEditText);

        addChangeListenersToTextEdit();

        visualCheckBox= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.visualCheckBox);
        auditoryCheckBox= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.auditoryCheckBox);
        selfInjuryCheckBox= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.selfInjuryCheckBox);

        setUpCheckBoxes();

        eatenRadioGroup= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.eatenRadioGroup);
        eatenOKRadioButton= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.eatenOkRadioButton);
        eatenPoorRadioButton= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.eatenPoorRadioButton);
        eatenWellRadioButton= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.eatenWellRadioButton);
        eatenNoneRadioButton= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.eatenNoneRadioButton);

        addChangeListenersToRadios();


        rateMoodSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.rateMoodSeekBar);
        rateMoodSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(rateMoodSeekBarListener);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        viewFilesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewFilesButton);
        setButtonOnClickListeners();






    }

    private void addChangeListenersToTextEdit() {
        moodAmountET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                rateMoodSeekBar.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(moodAmountET.getText().toString()));

            }

        });

    }

    private void addChangeListenersToRadios() {

        eatenRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                eaten = (eatenNoneRadioButton.isChecked())?"None":null;
                eaten = (eatenPoorRadioButton.isChecked())?"Poor":null;
                eaten = (eatenOKRadioButton.isChecked())?"OK":null;
                eaten = (eatenWellRadioButton.isChecked())?"Well":null;

            }

        });

    }

    private void setUpCheckBoxes() {
        visualCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                visual = isChecked;

            }

        });

        auditoryCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                auditory = isChecked;

            }

        });

        selfInjuryCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                selfInjury = isChecked;

            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener rateMoodSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {

            // Get the value set on the SeekBar

            moodAmount = (rateMoodSeekBar.getProgress());

            // Set tipAmountET with the value from the SeekBar


            moodAmountET.setText(String.format("%.00f", moodAmount));

            // Update all the other EditTexts

            //updateMood();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


        }

    };

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void updateMood(){

        // Get tip amount



        moodAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", moodAmount));

    }


    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putDouble(MOOD_AMOUNT, moodAmount);


    }
    private void setButtonOnClickListeners() {
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getInputData();
                writeSubmitInternal(inputData);
                //dialog box
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.submitted_alert);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.submitted_alert);
                AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
                theAlertDialog.show();
            }


        });



    }

    protected void getInputData() {
        String tempDataCompile;
        tempDataCompile = moodAmountET.getText().toString();
        tempDataCompile += " " + eaten;
        tempDataCompile += " " + String.valueOf(visual) + " " + String.valueOf(auditory) + " " + String.valueOf(selfInjury); //checkboxes
        inputData = tempDataCompile;
    }

    public void writeSubmitInternal(String data){
        String fileName;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String theYear = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        String theMonth = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        String theDay = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String theHour = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

        fileName = theYear+"_"+theMonth+ "_"+theDay+"_"+theHour+".txt";

        FileOutputStream outputStream;


        try {
          outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
          outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void nextScreen(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFilesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Second Activity

```
public class ListFilesActivity extends Activity {


    Button openFileButton;

    File[] fileList;
    String[] fileNames;


    Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_files);
        getFiles();

        //------------------

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fileSpinner);
        myAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fileNames);
        myAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter1);

        openFileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openFileButton);
        openFileButton.setOnClickListener(openFileButtonListener);


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_files, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void getFiles(){
        File path = this.getFilesDir();
        fileList = path.listFiles();
        fileNames[0] = "None";
        if(fileList[0]!=null){
            for(int i = 0; i<fileList.length;i++){
                fileNames[i]=fileList[i].getName();
            }
        }
    }


    public void deleteSingleFile(String fileName){
        int index=-1;
        for(int i = 0; i<fileNames.length;i++){
            index = fileNames[i].equals(fileName)?i:-1;
        }
        if (index==-1){
            displayAlert("File Not Found");
        }
        else{
            fileList[index].delete();
        }
    }

    private void displayAlert(String message) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListFilesActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Alert");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
        theAlertDialog.show();

    }

    public void deleteAllFiles(){
        getFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i<fileList.length;i++){
            fileList[i].delete();
        }
    }

    public OnClickListener openFileButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        }


    };

}
```

and the data log:

```
11-26 21:08:08.877: D/AndroidRuntime(20621): Shutting down VM
11-26 21:08:08.877: W/dalvikvm(20621): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception       (group=0x41622d40)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621): Process: tumblr.worldofmyown.mood_app_android, PID:   20621
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{tumblr.worldofmyown.mood_app_android/tumblr.worldofmyown.mood_app_android.ListFilesActi    vity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
 11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at    tumblr.worldofmyown.mood_app_android.ListFilesActivity.getFiles(ListFilesActivity.java:73)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at tumblr.worldofmyown.mood_app_android.ListFilesActivity.onCreate(ListFilesActivity.java:33)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
11-26 21:08:08.882: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    ... 11 more
11-26 21:08:11.644: I/Process(20621): Sending signal. PID: 20621 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The line 73, which one is it in the code you posted?

Comment: cause is a NullPointerException, stacktrace explains everything, Just put a breakpoint before line 73 of ListFilesActivity and debug and see which variable is null and apply the fix.

Comment: Is the fileNames array initialized before you use it on `fileNames[0] = "None";`?? I think the problem is the absence of size definition.

Comment: Have you added `ListFilesActivity` in Android Manifest?